# adding date and time while converting m2ts to mp4 using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, date, mp4, m2ts

I have many m2ts video files which were created by Sony camcorder. Because they are my family history, I want to see the date and time when I play them. But no players have such functions. I think I have to create new video files whose source is m2ts and its meta data. While the internet surfing, I guess that ffmpeg may do it but no solution for what I faced in.(generally put current time or specified time, not using meta data of the source file)

Here is my situation and what I want to do using ffmpeg.

1. I have so many m2ts files(its playing time is less than 5 mins, generally) which were created by Sony camcorder.
2. I want to convert m2ts files to mp4 files using ffmpeg.
3. During the converting, I want to put date and time which is originally contained in the meta data space of m2ts file on the mp4's "screen", not mp4's meta data space. So, when I play the converted mp4 file, I could see yyyy-mm-dd above hh-mm-am(or pm).
4. I want to merge converted mp4 files to one whose playing time is generally one hour.

So, my questions are
(1) how to do #3,date and time format I specified such as yyyy-mm-dd and hh-mm-am(pm) format using ffmpeg
(2) how to merge converted mp4 files using ffmpeg

Please help me..

Comment: It might be a LOT easier to just have the video player show the filename on screen, assuming the filename has the date in it